# Set R to include missing data – How can is set the `useNA="ifany"` option for `table()` as default?

Tags: r, default, analysis, missing-data

In many cases being aware of missing data is crucial and ignoring them can seriously impair your analysis.

Therefore I'd like to set the `useNA = "ifany"` as default for `table()`. Ideally similar to `options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`

I found an ugly hack below, but it must go better and without defining a function.

https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2010-January/223871.html

```
tableNA<-function(x) {
  varname<-deparse(substitute(x))
  assign(varname,x)
  tabNA<-table(get(varname),useNA="always")
  names(attr(tabNA,"dimnames"))<-varname
  return(tabNA)
}
```

Comment: `tableNA <- function(...) table(..., useNA="ifany")`?

Comment: without defining a new function?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well you do need to define a function<sup>1</sup> but you can *reuse* the existing name (and make the definition much leaner):

```
table = function (..., useNA = 'ifany') base::table(..., useNA = useNA)
```

This will make the new functionality available under the old name – but only in your code, so it’s “safe” (i.e. it doesn’t change packages’ use of `table`).

We use `...` to allow arbitrary arguments to be passed, and we give `useNA` the desired default value of `'ifany'`. Inside the function, we just call the “real” `table` function. But in order to avoid calling ourselves, we specify the namespace in which it’s found: `base`. And we just pass all the arguments untouched.

---

<sup>1</sup> Just look at the source code of `table` – it doesn’t query any option in setting the argument, so there can be no way of determining the setting of that argument via an option.

Comment: Can you briefly expand what's going on in your code or why this syntax works?

Comment: Also I suggest `<-` for consistency.

Comment: @Rico I suggest `=` for consistency. I used to use `<-` until a few weeks ago but there’s really no reason for it. I’ll update the answer with an explanation.

Comment: Ah I was expecting `{}` but they are implicit.

Comment: @Rico `{}` in R are used only for one single purpose: to group several expressions and treat them as one. You never need parentheses around a single expression (and indeed I strongly recommend not using them in such case).